# Indices of the transposed matrix of vectors

Tags: matrices

I am Writing a computer program in "CUDA C++", it does not matter what does the program do. The thing that matters is I need to rearrange the elements in the array.

The reason for this is to improve the program performance (in terms of the execution time). My experience taught me that the right arrangement of the elements in the array (which is basically a vector) may accelerate the program up to ten times, and sometimes even more (depends on the problem).

In this specific case, I am working with $2$D array. I choose to represent this as a matrix and work with it as such, but I am open to new ideas.

---

**Exact explanation of the problem:**

Let's assume I have a matrix $N$x$M = 3$x$4$. 
(entries are labelled with the pairs $\{$ row index, column index$\}$).

$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\{0,0\} & \{0,1\} & \{0,2\} & \{0,3\} \\
\{1,0\} & \{1,1\} & \{1,2\} & \{1,3\} \\
\{2,0\} & \{2,1\} & \{2,2\} & \{2,3\} \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

I can also label each entry of the matrix above with the linear index. 
Using the expression: $ i \cdot M + j $ where $(i, j)$ are row and column indexes.

$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
 0 &  1 &  2 &  3 \\
 4 &  5 &  6 &  7 \\
 8 &  9 & 10 & 11 \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

Now, let's assume each entry of the $3$x$4$ matrix above is a vector, but things are now getting a bit tricky because I need to consider two situations:

---

**Case #1:** 
Vectors in columns $\{ 0, 1, 2, ...,  M - 2 \} = \{ 0, 1, 2 \}$ (in this example) have $k$ elements each. 
Let's assume $k = 4$.

Vectors in the last column $\{ M - 1 \} = \{ 3 \}$ have $w$ elements. $w$ can be anywhere in between: $w = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, ... K - 1 \} = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3 \}$ (in this example). 
Let's assume $w = 3$ for the sake of the example.

$w = 0$ is a special case when the last column of the $3$x$4$ matrix is filled with "empty" entries, and the problem simplifies to the case where we are working with $3$x$3$ matrix of the $k$ element vectors.

**Visualization:**
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\left[ 0, 1, 2, 3 \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2, 3 \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2, 3 \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2    \right] \\
\left[ 0, 1, 2, 3 \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2, 3 \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2, 3 \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2    \right] \\
\left[ 0, 1, 2, 3 \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2, 3 \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2, 3 \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2    \right] \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

And again each vector's element can be given a unique linear ID:
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\left[  0,  1,  2,  3 \right] & 
\left[  4,  5,  6,  7 \right] & 
\left[  8,  9, 10, 11 \right] & 
\left[ 12, 13, 14     \right] \\
\left[ 15, 16, 17, 18 \right] & 
\left[ 19, 20, 21, 22 \right] & 
\left[ 23, 24, 25, 26 \right] & 
\left[ 27, 28, 29     \right] \\
\left[ 30, 31, 32, 33 \right] & 
\left[ 34, 35, 36, 37 \right] & 
\left[ 38, 39, 40, 41 \right] & 
\left[ 42, 43, 44     \right] \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

---

**Case #2:** 
is very similar to the "Case #1" but now vectors in the last row can have a different size than the rest.

**Visualization:**
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\left[ 0, 1, 2, 3 \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2, 3 \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2, 3 \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2, 3 \right] \\
\left[ 0, 1, 2, 3 \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2, 3 \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2, 3 \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2, 3 \right] \\
\left[ 0, 1, 2    \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2    \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2    \right] & 
\left[ 0, 1, 2    \right] \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

---

**Long story short:**

I need a set of functions:

$$ F(q) = \{ i, j , l \} $$
$$ W(i, j , l ) = q $$
where:

- $q$ is the unique ID of the element of the vector.
- $i$ is the matrix entry row index. (row index of the vector in the matrix)
- $j$ is the matrix entry column index. (column index of the vector in the matrix)
- $l$ is the id of the element of the vector. (not unique, $l \in \{0, 1, 2, ..., k - 1\}$)

---

I want to calculate a $ F(q) = \{ i, j , l \} $, then calculate $ W(j, i, l ) = q`$

So i could transpose the matrix:

$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\left[  0,  1,  2,  3 \right] & 
\left[  4,  5,  6,  7 \right] & 
\left[  8,  9, 10, 11 \right] & 
\left[ 12, 13, 14     \right] \\
\left[ 15, 16, 17, 18 \right] & 
\left[ 19, 20, 21, 22 \right] & 
\left[ 23, 24, 25, 26 \right] & 
\left[ 27, 28, 29     \right] \\
\left[ 30, 31, 32, 33 \right] & 
\left[ 34, 35, 36, 37 \right] & 
\left[ 38, 39, 40, 41 \right] & 
\left[ 42, 43, 44     \right] \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

into this one:

$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\left[  0,  1,  2,  3 \right] & 
\left[ 15, 16, 17, 18 \right] &
\left[ 30, 31, 32, 33 \right] \\
\left[  4,  5,  6,  7 \right] & 
\left[ 19, 20, 21, 22 \right] & 
\left[ 34, 35, 36, 37 \right] \\
\left[  8,  9, 10, 11 \right] & 
\left[ 23, 24, 25, 26 \right] & 
\left[ 38, 39, 40, 41 \right] \\
\left[ 12, 13, 14     \right] &
\left[ 27, 28, 29     \right] &
\left[ 42, 43, 44     \right] 
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

---

**Question:**

How can I derive the set of the equations mentioned above ("Long story short")? I am not interested in a ready solution. Unfortunately, I deal a lot lately with this kind of problems. And I would like to know a way to solve them on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be too bad. I will focus on the case where the elements (vectors) in the last column have a different dimension than the elements in the first $m-1$ columns.... So, Assume you are given an $n\times m$ matrix where the (vectors) of the first $m-1$ columns have $k_1$ elements, and the vectors in the last column each have $k_2$ elements. If we count the elements in each vector for each vector in some particular row (say row $i$), we get

$\sum _{j=1} ^{m} |A_{ij}|$
 $=$  $\sum _{j=1} ^{m-1} |A_{ij}|+ \sum _{j=m-1} ^{m} |A_{ij}|$

Each term in the sum on left has value $k_1$ and the single term in the sum on the right (the size of the vector in the last column) is $k_2$

Thus we have $(m-1 \cdot k_1 )$$+k_2$ elements in each row. Call this quantity $Q$

Since there are $n$ rows, you have exactly $n\cdot Q$ elements total.

Now, given $l$ (some id of an element as you described) you can first determine the row by computing $\lfloor \frac{l}{Q} \rfloor$ (floor function). Call this value $V$

The same idea applies to finding the column. Once you know your row, you are essentially "starting from 0" when counting over columns, so to figure out how many elements into the given row $l$ is, compute
$l - V\cdot Q$ (or use the mod function and take $l$ mod $Q$).

The quantity $l - V\cdot Q$ tells you the number of elements you need to count over in the given row in order to find your element. I would break this into two cases,

case 1) If  $l - V\cdot Q \geq (m-1)\cdot k$ then you know you are in the last column and it should be smooth sailing from there.

case 2) o.w. $l - V\cdot Q < (m-1)\cdot k$
to determine the column just compute:
$col$=$\lfloor (l - V\cdot Q )/ k \rfloor$

Last, the element number in the vector is given by the remainder of (l - V\cdot Q )/ k, i.e.$elt_in_vector=(l - V\cdot Q )/ \mod k$

Let me know if you have any questions. It's tough to get this stuff perfect first try, i probably made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @mm8511i implemented your solution, it works great. unfortunately, I have a problem with calculating $W(i, j, e)=l$ where: `i`,`j`, row and column index, `e` is vector element index, `l` is a unique index. I have found an equation which lets me calculate `l` correctly but when I try to transpose the matrix (e.g. calculate $W(j, i, e)=l'$ the result is wrong. Do you have any idea how to do this? My equation: $W(i, j, e) = i \cdot Q + \lfloor \frac{j}{k_{1}} \rfloor \cdot  k_{1} + e $ when i transpose ${i, j}$ some results are wrong.